# ClassCastException occurs when calling another fragment's method

Tags: java, android, fragment, classcastexception

**Re-attached the relevant code

---

When I run the email app in FragmentB, the activity's 'onStop' is called.
At this time, FragmentA's method in 'onStop' does not work.

※ FragmentA and FragmentB have the same parent Activity
※ No error occurs when the app is terminated in FragmentB.

**MainActivity.java**

```
   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    
    public Fragment fragmentA, fragmentB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            fragmentA = new FragmentA();
            fragmentB = new FragmentB();
           
            fragmentA.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
           
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentA).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
      
        ((FragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)).saveData();

    }

}
```

**FragmentA.java**

```
    View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, container, false);
    if(isLoadData){ loadData(); }
    return view;
}

public void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences timerSharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("timer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    
    //...
    
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = timerSharedPref.edit();
    String json = jsonArray.toString();
    editor.putString("jsonString", json);
    editor.apply();
}
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

View view;
CardView cvContactUs;
MainActivity activity;

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    activity = null;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    cvContactUs = view.findViewById(R.id.cv_contact_us);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    cvContactUs.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.cv_contact_us) {
        sendEmail(getActivity(), "Ask a question", new String[]{"help_center@gmail.com"});
    }
}
public static void sendEmail(Context context, String title, String[] receivers){
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, receivers);
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    context.startActivity(email);
}
```

}

Comment: did you try `findFragmentByTag()`;?

Comment: depending on the error you have you have not taken the right fragment

Comment: I made it using findFragmentByTag(), but it's the same as if I'm not good at using it. I have attached all the relevant codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two Fragments in the stack and a single ID and the `findFragmentByID()` method returns the last fragment added to the container. very well when the application ends with the FragmentA I believe that you don't have any error because in the `onStop()` method you are casting with the **FragmentA**, but if you end with the **FragmentB** in this case you are casting the **FragmentB** by the **FragmentA** which throws the ***ClassCastException*** exception. so I suggest you use the `findFragmentByTag()` method here is an example

When you add fragments:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*
         * rest of your code
         */
        // when you add the Fragment A
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentA(), "A")
                .commit();
        // when you add the Fragment A
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentB(), "B")
                .commit();
    }
```

and when you call the onStop() methode:

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // ((FragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("A")).save();
        // ((FragmentB) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("B")).save();
        Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("A");
        // you check if the fragment is add 
        if (f != null)
            ((FragmentA) f).save();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks solved the problem. Thanks for the kind explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

You say you are getting a ClassCastException. The only class cast from the code you posted is

```
(FragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(...)
```

So check whether findFragmentById might return FragmentB or something else. Maybe you want to

- either cast to the common parent activity
- check whether the returned value is an instance of FragmentA before casting

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, so I re-attached the relevant code.

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace where the exception occurs? I just take ClassCastException fro the title of the question.

Comment: This was my first question, so there were many things that were lacking. I solved the problem with an answer from another person, but thank you very much for posting the answer :)